# Parsing input element using JSoup

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

JSoup is used to parse the following html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id12" name="renewalCheckboxGroup" value="check1" class="wicket-id11" />
```

Here is the code of JSoup

```
    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"id12\" name=\"renewalCheckboxGroup\" value=\"check1\" class=\"wicket-id11\" />");
    System.out.println(document.id());
```

**Expected result should be id12, however, the returned id is an empty string.**
I also try to call attribute("id") function as well, but still in vain.
How to solve it? Thank YOu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know you should select/find/extract your desired `Element` from your `document` and only then access its attribute (`id` for example)

You got several options:

```
Elements inputs = document.getElementsByTag("input"); //then access the one at 0 index
```

or

```
Element input = doc.getElementById("id12");
```

or

```
Elements inputs = doc.select("input[name=renewalCheckboxGroup]"); //then access the one at 0 index
```

take a look at the docs for more options...

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

[Use DOM methods to navigate a document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)