# How to parse html tag from response of responsebody in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

My code is as shown below:

```
   private void testInfo() {
        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(LogInActivity.this)) {
            Observable<ResponseBody> results = RetroClient.getApiService()
                    .testInfo("Basic NTcyODQ4MDc0NzEzNTIwOToxMjhiNTNkMS1iMTc2LTQxOTEtYWJmYS1hN2RhYjIzYmFjMzk=", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            "John Q. Test", "Visa", "4747474747474747", 12, 25, 999, "123 A. Street",
                            "Orem", "UT", "84058", "USA", "4355824", "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");
//            showProgressBar();
            results.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            unsubscribe();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
//                            hideProgressBar();
                            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(ResponseBody response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onNext: " + response.string());
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, R.string.string_internet_connection_warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Now for this, I get the following as my response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./spr.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="k2sKy+QLc68jCgZVuadfy2ONS4SO3c0" />
    <div>
    <div id="PanelPleaseWait">


<div style="min-height: 10em; display: block; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;">
    <h3>
        Processing, please wait...</h3>
    Please wait, your transaction is processing. Please don't hit back or stop.<br />
    <img src="images/bigrotation.gif" />
</div>


</div>
    </div>
    <input name="ResponseCipher" type="hidden" id="ResponseCipher" value="6s31abi0RZUSAw3Iwk0db9irVWKTi2+UtpSVTUE7DKlhWqLd1WBlQ==" /></form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].action='http://krl.in/';
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

Here, what I want is , I want to access `value` of input with id `ResponseCipher`. What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: I think thats the server side error..this should not come in your response..something is not right from your backend

Comment: Actually , this is third party API and this is their only response

Comment: JSOUP is for parsing html. But as there is only one value attibute in the whole html source you can parse it out your self using substring() and other text functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is a library lets you parse numerous HTML tags/attributes off String.
Just parse your desire input Id and you should access the value as well.

Take a look at the following sources.

- [Parsing HTML in Android with Jsoup](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup-2.html)
- [Parsing input element using JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068546/parsing-input-element-using-jsoup)